# Pooled Kurtosis Estimator Using Pooled Cumulant Estimators

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, kurtosis, pooling, cumulants

I am trying to come up with a statistically sensible **pooled kurtosis estimator** that is based on **pooled cumulant estimators**.

Specifically, I have unbiased estimators of the second and fourth cumulant in this form ([1](http://www.mathstatica.com/book/Rose_and_Smith_2002edition_Chapter7.pdf), p. 257):
$$
k_2 = \frac{n m_2}{n-1}\\
k_4 = \frac{n^2 \left(-3 m_2^2 (n-1)+m_4 n+m_4\right)}{(n-3)
   (n-2) (n-1)},
$$
where $m_r$ is the $r$-th sample central moment, i.e., $m_r = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\bar{x}\right){}^r$, and $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean.
A possible estimator for the (non-excess) kurtosis is
$$
G_2=\frac{k_4}{k_2^2} + 3.
$$

My goal is to use pooled estimators $k_{2 pooled}$ and $k_{4 pooled}$ for $k_2$ and $k_4$ to ultimately come up with a pooled estimator for the kurtosis $G_{2 pooled}$.
I.e.,
$$
G_{2 pooled} = \frac{k_{4 pooled}}{(k_{2 pooled})^2}+3.
$$

$k_{2 pooled}$ seems to be straightforward to derive, as it is equivalent to the [pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance):
$$
k_{2 pooled}=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^m (n_j-1)k_{2 j}}{\sum_{j=1}^m (n_j-1)}.
$$
Here, the terms subscripted with $j$ refer to the respective terms for the $j$-th population (from a total of $m$ populations).
However, I am unsure about $k_{4 pooled}$.
I *suppose* that it should be in this form:
$$
k_{4 pooled}=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^m w_{4 j}\,k_{4 j}}{\sum_{j=1}^m w_{4 j}},
$$
But I do not know what I should use for $w_{4 j}$.
I understand that $w_{4 j}$ ought to be the degrees of freedom, which is, for the fourth sample cumulant, $n-3$, *I guess*?
Thus, $w_{4 j} = n_j-3$?

I would highly appreciate it if someone could put an end to my guesswork and provide a definitive answer on how to calculate $k_{4 pooled}$ in order to calculate $G_{2 pooled}$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You might want to clarify what "statistically sensible" means, as a first step toward a solution. There are many criteria, and you can't have everything.

Comment: I agree that "statistically sensible" was a bit vague. Thanks for pointing this out! My goal is to obtain an unbiased pooled estimator of the fourth sample cumulant $k_{4 pooled}$ (for non-uniform sample sizes). In the case of the second sample cumulant (variance), an unbiased pooled estimator can be obtained by weighting the variances with Bessel's correction (n-1). I essentially would like to know the analogous weight for the fourth sample cumulant.